# Fetch ParseObject data based on relations query

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've question about way in which I should create query to get expected data.

I've MyObject (ParseObject) which has pointer to ParseUser (column named createdByPtr). In ParseUser I have custom column userGroupPtr.

Now I want to get all MyObject rows which are created by all users (createdByPtr) belongs to user group (userGroupPtr) to which belongs current logged user (ParseUser.CurrentUser()).
At this moment I have some kind of draft like this:

```
ParseQuery<MyObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(MyObject.class);
        query.include("createdByPtr");
        query.whereEqualTo("createdByPtr.userGroupPtr", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("userGroupPtr"));
        query.orderByDescending("updatedAt");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<MyObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<MyObject> results, ParseException e) {
                ....
            }
        });
```

I don't have idea how should I transform line:

```
query.whereEqualTo("createdByPtr.userGroupPtr", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().get("userGroupPtr"));
```

in to working constrain.

Any suggestions?

Comment: see my edited anwser.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this. I have tested and it works perfectly. see [Relational Queries](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries#RelationalQueries)

```
 ParseQuery<ParseUser> innerQuery = ParseUser.getQuery();
    innerQuery.whereEqualTo("userGroupPtr","userGroupPtr"); //value of userGroupPtr
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery(MyObject.class);
    query.whereMatchesQuery("createdByPtr", innerQuery);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
      public void done(List<ParseObject> objectList, ParseException e) {

          if(e == null){

          }else{
              Log.e("Object", e.getMessage());
          }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. In result list I don't have any items. I'm not sure if this constrain "MyObject.ColumnPtr" is valid in Parse. I included it in my main query as example to what I want to get.